# Story about surrogate mother

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title of a science fiction story, where the following are part of the story:

- An ape, gorilla or some other creature, probably named Al, who may or may not have set fire to the lab at the end of the story.
- Al is somewhat disfigured.
- The surrogate mothers are cows (could be some other animals)
- The babies are humans.

This is a full length sci fi novel which was published between 1970-1998.

Does someone know the title of this novel?

Comment: Hey this sounds kind of familiar... Are the babies implanted into the cows, like in vitro?

Comment: Ahh I found the book I was thinking of, The House of the Scorpion. Don't think it fits this description though, besides the surrogate cow mommy part.

Comment: Bobo, not House of the Scorpion. House of the Scorpion was published in 2002. So it doesn't fall in the timeline I gave.

Comment: @chuacw true, but he missed the timeframe by just 4 years in 28, it's quite usual to misremember a date, especially if you gave such an enormously large range.

Comment: Sorry still learning etiquette as newbe, put something as answer but really its only a suggestion from memory: Stephen Gallagher's 1983 novel chimera has an ape human hybrid, and fits the questioner's 1970-88 timescale better.

Comment: @SimonBucher-Jones: 
You're fine to put the answer up. You just need to explain why it fits. Does it match at all for the gorilla or cow aspects?

Comment: This seems to be correct, Simon. Is there an ape named Al or a person who worked at the lab, who was compassionate, helped to save most of the characters and eventually started a fire, or died in a fire or something? I might have mixed some of the details up.

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't include Chimera as an answer.